# Importrange, editing from the sheet that its imported too

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I currently use importrange to get timesheets to a master sheet. I then download this sheet every week and update to my KPI's

As all the information is on the master sheet where all data is importrange data, I would like to delete/refresh the timesheets from there too.

At the moment I have to go into everyone's timesheet separately to wipe with a button I made. However, I would like to wipe them all using a button in the master sheet, being they're all importrange data from many other sheets, it won't let me delete data to refresh all from one page.

Basically, I wish to edit importrange data from the master sheet, but currently, it only works one way, is there a way for it to let me change the original sheet from the importrange? Or even a different type of import?

I hope this makes sense and hopefully you can help me.

Comment: `Importrange` - Just want to confirm that you do understand that once the data is deleted from the timesheet, it is also deleted from your Master sheet - you have no historical record (unless you copy/paste the data before you delete it. _it won't let me delete data to refresh all from one page._  Do you have permission to `edit` in the timesheets? I can't see why you couldn't have a list of timesheets, with the values of the url and range string_ of each `IMPORTRANGE`. Then write a script (and put it in a custom menu), that will delete the range_string of each url.